# extract sentence that has a pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset with unstructured text data.

From the text I want to extract sentences that have the following words:

```
education_vector <- c("university", "academy", "school", "college")
```

For example, from the text `I am a student at the University of Wyoming. My major is biology.`  I want to get `I am a student at the University of Wyoming.`

From the text `I love statistics and I enjoy working with numbers. I graduated from Walla Wall Community College`  I want to get `I graduated from Walla Wall Community College.` and so on

I tried using `grep` function but it returned wrong results

Comment: Please include the way that you called grep in your question.

Comment: grep(paste(education_vector, collapse = '|'),unlist(strsplit(str1, "(.*?)\\..*")),  unlist(strsplit(str1, '(?<=\\.)\\s+', perl=TRUE)), value=TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer modified to select *first* match.

```
texts = c("I am a student at the University of Wyoming. My major is biology.",
"I love statistics and I enjoy working with numbers. I graduated from Walla Wall Community College",
"First, I went to the Bowdoin College. Then I went to the University of California.")

gsub(".*?([^\\.]*(university|academy|school|college)[^\\.]*).*", 
    "\\1", texts, ignore.case=TRUE)

[1] "I am a student at the University of Wyoming"   
[2] " I graduated from Walla Wall Community College"
[3] "First, I went to the Bowdoin College"
```

Explanation:
`.*?` is a non-greedy match up to the rest of the pattern. This is there to remove any sentences before the relevant sentence.

`([^\\.]*(university|academy|school|college)[^\\.]*)` matches any string of characters *other than* a period immediately before and after one of the key words.

`.*` handles anything after the relevant sentence.

This replaces the entire string with only the relevant part.

Comment: How to get the first match? My examples were just demo. Your code works, but in real, my texts are big and sometimes it doesn't return the first match

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `grep`

```
education <- c("university", "academy", "school", "college")

str1 <- "I am a student at the University of Wyoming. My major is biology."
str2 <- "I love statistics and I enjoy working with numbers. I graduated from Walla Wall Community College"
str1 <- tolower(str1) # we use tolower because "university" != "University"
str2 <- tolower(str2)

grep(paste(education, collapse = "|"), unlist(strsplit(str1, "(?<=\\.)\\s+",
                                                       perl = TRUE)),
     value = TRUE)

grep(paste(education, collapse = "|"), unlist(strsplit(str2, "(?<=\\.)\\s+",
                                                       perl = TRUE)),
     value = TRUE)
```